# How to shift letters to the right or left?

Tags: c

I am given a file with a string, for example `"The United States was founded in *1776*"`. What I cannot figure out is how to shift letters one space to the left or right and have the letters wrap around. I am able to shift the letters from an a to b but not change its location within the word.
Example of this output would be:

```
"heT
nitedU
tatesS
asw
oundedf
ni
1776**"
```

Comment: Exactly the same as if you would do that manually. How would you do that manually? Imagine a box with 6 sections and `nitedU` letters in every section. How would you rearrange those?

Comment: Note it's easier to output in that manner than to move characters in that manner within program memory. Which do you need?

Comment: @zerkms if I am understanding your question correctly you just shift the letter on to the left

Comment: @aschepler I need to have it output the letters to one spot to the left not the actual program location.

Comment: @RollTide1234 if you just need to output it - read the last letter, then all but the last one.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yep, I type quicker than I think, sorry.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes 'saw' is supposed to be 'asw'. And when I tried to type a word between two asterisks it italicizes the word which I do not want it to be italicized.

Comment: @RollTide1234 Is the double quotation mark(`"`) actually included as the contents of the file? Should it be treated as an exception? Also, does it just need an output and You don't actually shift the character?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no I was just trying to separate the string from the text of the question. I am not familiar with how to correctly format everything on here so I do the best I can.

Comment: " I am able to shift the letters from an a to b" --> post the code that does that to narrow the scope of what code is attempting.

Comment: @RollTide1234 Is the shift amount and direction specified by something? Processing is easy if it does not actually rotate but just displays it as in the example.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/M9sQqC)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am trying to code for a cipher and we have encryption letters  stated in the command line that need to be read. In this case if the encryption letter is L it will shift the letters to the left and if the letter is R it will shift the letters to the right.

Comment: @RollTide1234 Is the amount of shift always one?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes the shift amount should always be one, but if in the command line there is an LL or RR then it will be shifted twice but I was thinking I could have it ran twice so that it would shift the letters once and then run again to shift them once more.

Comment: @RollTide1234 I posted example code as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, strings are stored as an array of chars in memory. Unlike C++ vectors, you can not insert or remove element within the array, you can only access their value or change their value.

If you declare a C string as follows:

```
char *myStr = "Fred";
```

It will be stored in memory as a five character array with the 5th character being the zero value which terminates a C string:

```
myStr[0] = 'F'
myStr[1] = 'r'
myStr[2] = 'e'
myStr[3] = 'd'
myStr[4] =  0
```

You need to design a `for` loop that copies each array element to the one before, while remembering that you need to save the one you are about to overwrite. In this example, it should result in the following copy operations being performed:

```
len      = strlen(myStr);
saveCh   = myStr[0];
myStr[0] = myStr[1]; 
myStr[1] = myStr[2];
myStr[2] = myStr[3];
myStr[3] = saveCh;
```

So now your job is to create a `for` loop that does that for any C string of any length.

So to rotate the chars within a C string to the left, you need to copy each char in the array at index i to previous array element i-1. The tricky part is to handle the wrap around properly when i=0 (in this example, you want to copy `myStr[0]` to `myStr[3]`. Now do that with a `for` loop.

You need to also understand that the last character of any C string is the null character (value zero), which terminates a C string. If you modify that element in the array, then your string will break. That is why `saveCh` is copied to `myStr[3]` and not to `myStr[4]`.

```
void rotateStrLeftOneChar(char *myStr) {
   // Always check for error and special cases first!
   // If myStr is a NULL pointer, do nothing and exit
   // If myStr is less than 2 chars, nothing needs to be done too.
   if ((myStr != NULL) && (strlen(myStr)>1)) {
      int  len    = strlen(myStr);
      char saveCh = myStr[0];
      int  i      = 0;

      // Copy each char at index i+1 left to index i in the array
      for(i=0; i<len-2; i++)
         myStr[i] = myStr[i+1];

      // The last character is special and is set to saveCh
      myStr[len-1] = saveCh;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to output the letters to shift to the left and don't want to change original input then you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shiftletters(char * input, int i);

int main () {

    char input[256];
    int shift;

    printf("Enter input : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", input);

    printf("Number of shifts : ");
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    shiftletters(input, shift);

    return 0;
}

void shiftletters(char * input, int numshifts)
{
    char str[256] = {'\0'};
    char * delim = " \t";
    char * pch = NULL;
    int j, k, len, shifts;

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Invalid input\n");
        return;
    }

    strcpy (str, input);
    pch = strtok (str, delim);
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen (pch);
        if ((numshifts == len) || (len == 1))
        {
            printf ("%s\n", pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, delim);
            continue;
        }

        if (len < numshifts)
            shifts = numshifts % len;
        else
            shifts = numshifts;

        for(j=shifts; j<len; j++)
            printf("%c", pch[j]);

        for(k=0; k<shifts; k++)
            printf("%c", pch[k]);

        printf("\n");
        pch = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
}
```

The output of the program:

```
Enter input : The United States was founded in *1776*
Number of shifts : 1
heT
nitedU
tatesS
asw
oundedf
ni
1776**
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { L = -1, R = 1};

char *rotate(char word[], int dir){
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    char *temp = malloc(len + 1);
    if(!temp){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(temp, word);
    for(char *src = temp; *src; ++src, ++dir){//or use memmove
        word[(dir+len)%len] = *src;
    }
    free(temp);
    return word;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s L|R...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char word[64];
    while(fscanf(fp, "%63s", word)==1){
        for(char *shift = argv[1]; *shift; ++shift){
            int dir = *shift == 'L' ? L : R;
            rotate(word, dir);
        }
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

using memmove version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { L = -1, R = 1};

char *rotate1(char word[], int dir){
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    if(len > 2){
        char temp;
        if(dir == L){
            temp = word[0];
            memmove(word, word+1, len-1);
            word[len-1] = temp;
        } else if(dir == R){
            temp = word[len-1];
            memmove(word+1, word, len-1);
            word[0] = temp;
        }
    }
    return word;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s L|R...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char word[64];
    while(fscanf(fp, "%63s", word)==1){
        for(char *shift = argv[1]; *shift; ++shift){
            int dir = *shift == 'L' ? L : R;
            rotate1(word, dir);
        }
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }
}
```